# Iterate over directory one by one and upload one file at a time

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, opencv, video

I am stuck with the data structure of this function I designed. The role of this function should be to pick index1 file from each directory and upload it and then go to the second index for each directory. The current design accomplishes the task but it uploads all the files for the first directory and then moves to the second directory and so on.

```
def open_rep(rootdir, folders, idx):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir, topdown=False):

        for d in dirs:
            print(d)

        for frame in files:
            if frame.lower().endswith(('.png','.jpg')): #if frame!=None:
                frame=os.path.join(folder, frame)

                print( 'Uploading '+str(frame) )
                file=upload_images(frame, idx)
                print( 'Removing '+str(frame)+' from local directory\n' )
                os.remove(frame)
            else:
                print('Folder '+str(folder)+' Empty')
                t.sleep(5.0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you're missing is the `break` keyword:

```
def open_rep(rootdir, folders, idx):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir, topdown=False):

        for d in dirs:
            print(d)

        for frame in files:
            if frame.lower().endswith(('.png','.jpg')): #if frame!=None:
                frame=os.path.join(folder, frame)

                print( 'Uploading '+str(frame) )
                file=upload_images(frame, idx)
                print( 'Removing '+str(frame)+' from local directory\n' )
                os.remove(frame)

                break # <- here
            else:
                print('Folder '+str(folder)+' Empty')
                t.sleep(5.0)
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but it won't work in my case as the `upload_images` function is using a list of folders (which tells which image should go in which folder) for which I pass 'idx'.